# Finding unknown non-English characters in a text file (python)

Tags: python, string, text

Suppose that we have a text file loading with:

```
file = open('my_file.txt',mode='r')
stg = file.read()
```

This file contains some non-English unknown characters. These characters may have different forms like `Á`, `î`, `Ç`, etc. How can I extract these characters with their location in the text file? So the output is the list of these characters with their locations (line number).

Comment: @Carl_M You're really complaining that the input file doesn't exist on your computer?

Comment: @JohnGordon, I am not complaining at all. Out of respect for the 3,574  reputation points held by the questioner, I was trying to provide a gentle reminder that  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies to questions.

Comment: @Carl_M I disagree that the error should be pointed out, and I don't think it's an example of a lack of an mcve. There are many cases in which someone may not provide instantly copy-pastable code. Let's say someone was asking about a discord bot, and they omit their token in `bot.run()`. Should one leave a comment stating that the code produces errors despite the fix being trivial?

Answer (score 2):

So assuming you wan't to find all non-[english, number, punctuation, backslash] characters you can use the following code to find all positions and numbers

```
[(match.start(0), match.group()) for match in re.finditer(f'[^a-zA-Z0-9{string.punctuation}\\\]', stg)]
```

Using example

```
ÁbxcsdasîîîîîîîîîîîîÇÇadasda/.1.32131.!#@%$%&*^()|\}}"?>:{}?><<"
```

It will return

```
[(0, 'Á'), (8, 'î'), (9, 'î'), (10, 'î'), (11, 'î'), (12, 'î'), (13, 'î'), (14, 'î'), (15, 'î'), (16, 'î'), (17, 'î'), (18, 'î'), (19, 'î'), (20, 'Ç'), (21, 'Ç')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which I used for one of my projects. It doesn't check for punctuations and special characters.

```
file = open('test.txt',mode='r')
lines = file.readlines()

def isEnglishChar(s):
    try:
        s.encode(encoding='utf-8').decode('ascii')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

for index, value in enumerate(lines):
    for i in range(0, len(value)):
        bool = isEnglishChar(value[i])
        if(not bool):
            print (value[i], index+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

ASCII characters have Unicode values between 0 and 127.  Any character with a Unicode value greater than 127 is not ASCII.

```
with open(filename) as fp:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
        for ch in line:
            if ord(ch) > 127:
                print(lineno, ch)
```

Comment: Used the above snippet in the answer I provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("testfile.txt", 'w') as f_out:
    test_text= '''
    This file contains some non-English unknown characters. 
    These characters may have different forms like Á, 
    î, Ç, etc. How can I extract these characters with their location in the text file
    '''
    f_out.write(test_text)
with open("testfile.txt") as fp:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
        ch_count = 0
        for ch in line:
            ch_count += 1
            if ord(ch) > 127:
                print(f'{lineno=}\tCharacter Number={ch_count}\t {ch=}')
```

Output

```
lineno=3    Character Number=52  ch='Á'
lineno=4    Character Number=5   ch='î'
lineno=4    Character Number=8   ch='Ç'
```

Comment: I am relatively new to StackOverflow. Like others, I have received a variety of comments with varying levels of politeness. I continue to try to master the material covered in: The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As well as PEP8 and PEP20,"The Zen of Python". All questions and comments on my answer are welcome.